# Limit data by user supplied date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a report for some historical data based on a user provided date range. The report will display monthly changes to all contracts based on the date range the user supplied.

There are 2 tables involved. The first is a ContractDetails table that has 1 line for every contract with all the required base information.

```
ContractID | LicenseID | StartDate  |  EndDate
---------- | --------- | ---------- | ----------
   304     |  ID-567   | 01/01/2018 | 12/31/2018
   331     |  ID-133   | 01/01/2015 | 12/31/2017
   1011    |  ID-257   | 06/06/2018 | 12/31/2018
   1359    |  ID-687   | 01/01/2018 | 12/31/2020
```

The Second Table is ContractChanges. Which basically just keeps a transnational history of changes to the contract with an FK on ContractID

```
 ID  | FK_ContractID | LicenseID | ChangeDate
---- | ------------- | --------- | ----------
 101 |      304      |   ID-123  | 12/28/2018
 102 |      331      |   ID-615  | 05/25/2018
 103 |      331      |   ID-994  | 10/31/2018
 104 |     1011      |   ID-498  | 04/04/2019
 105 |     1011      |   ID-701  | 04/04/2019
```

Assuming the user supplied the dates 11/1/2018 through 06/30/2019. The expected output would be as such:

```
ContractID | LicenseID | Month | Year
---------- | --------- | ----- | ----
   304     |   ID-567  |  Nov  | 2018
   304     |   ID-123  |  Dec  | 2018
   331     |   ID-994  |  Nov  | 2018
  1011     |   ID-257  |  Nov  | 2018
  1011     |   ID-701  |  Apr  | 2019
  1359     |   ID-687  |  Nov  | 2018
```

If no changes occurred in the date range supplied then show the original contract info in the first month (Nov in this case). 
Next if changes occurred then show the change that occurred within that month.
Lastly, if multiple changes occurred within the same month then use the last change for that contract.

This seems a fairly straight forward issue but what is throwing me off is the last requirement for when multiple changes happen within the same month.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: ... and what did you try to solve your issue?

Comment: Partition the rows by month and produce an inner row_number() in the month, using DESC order. Then just keep row numbers equal to 1, in order to discard previous entries in the same month.

Comment: @TheImpaler Your comment got me part of the way there. so I would give you the "answer" if i could. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documenting the logic as requested. **This answer is incomplete**, since it lacks date filtering.

You can refine this query to add the exact logic you need, but should be a good starting point:

```
select
  ContractID, LicenseID, m as [Month], y as [Year]
from (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by ContractID, y, m order by dt DESC) as rn
  from (
    select
      ContractID, LicenseID, StartDate as dt,
      month(StartDate) as m, year(StartDate) as y
    from ContractDetails
    union all 
    select
      FK_ContractID, LicenseID, ChangeDate,
      month(ChangeDate), year(ChangeDate)
    from ContractChanges
  ) x
) y
where rn = 1 -- this predicate keeps only the last row in each month
order by ContractID, y, m
```